# Drive.Files.remove(fileId) error when the script its over

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

i try to remove a file with `Drive.Files.remove(fileId)` before make some operations with `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` but it fails with the error

> Document 1b0pLioLpwZndFuW4kRQzxd5gkfZjWFIT5Qr8HV-LJvo is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

Here a copy of the code

```
function guardar () {
 var carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById('kcuahwd584awd4a8s54x6a8');
 var archivos = carpeta.getFiles();  
 var file ; 
 while(archivos.hasNext()){
  file = archivos.next();
  Logger.log(file.getId())  
  var excel = file   
  var entrada =SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ file.getId() +"/edit#gid=79286573")
  var salida = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl( 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ a4w6d8a4w6da4sxawda /edit#gid=0')
  var sheets = entrada.getSheets();

  salida = salida.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheets[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  for( var i = 3 ; i < data.length ; i++){
   salida.appendRow(data[i])
  }    
  excel.makeCopy(DriveApp.getFolderById("dkawdkuawhdkuawhdkauwdhcsx"));
}  
 borrar();
}


function borrar(){
 var carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById('awbdkwuhdkawudhkawuhd');
 var archivos = carpeta.getFiles();  
 var file ; 
  while(archivos.hasNext()){
    file = archivos.next();
    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId())  
  }
 }
```

i already try give it more time with a sleep but it doesn't work Thank you for your help guys

Comment: Did you add the Drive API Advanced Google Service to the resources of your Apps Script Project? Also note that: `Drive.Files.remove(id)` Permanently deletes a file by ID. Skips the trash. The currently authenticated user must own the file or be an organizer on the parent for shared drive files.

Comment: @Alessandro Your suggested edit is incorrect. There is no method signature `DriveApp.removeFile(fileId)` in the documentation, whereas  ``DriveApp.removeFile(file)`` exists: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removeFile(File)

Comment: @TheMaster I see, thanks for pointing that out. I believe I got confused. What I meant to edit is the fact that he was not using DriveApp to delete the file.